# Baud Rate Calculation

Tags: serial-port, byte, accelerometer, bit, baud-rate

I have this 3-axis dongle serial accelerometer connected using RS-232 cable. I am putting the baud rate as 9600 and im getting 80 XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ readout per second. I am trying to justify why does it shows 80 readings in a second, and here is my calculation,

2 Bytes of data x (1 Start bit + 1 Stop bit + 8 bits) = 20 bits
20 bits x 3 axis x 80 readouts = 4800 bits

While im getting 4800 bits instead of 9600 bits, so i am wondering did i miss out anything in justifying the 80 readouts?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: You are working under the assumption that the rate of data it is providing is limited by the serial connection.  This may or may not be true. It may simply generate samples at a fixed rate of 80 Hz. Adding information about the specific device you're using may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you're getting 80 `XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ` readouts per second. I'm assuming this is ASCII, so each digit is one byte.

So each "message" is `len('XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ')*8 = 112` bits long. Add a start and stop bit and you have 114. Multiply that times 80 messages per second, and you're transmitting 9120 bits per second, which is much close to the theoretical limit.

Comment: I think that the `XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ` is just a semantic terminology here, since OP explicitly states 20 bits x 3 axis, which implies 20 bits per single axis (not really sure how to say "axis" in single)...

Comment: @barakmanos Without device specifics, we have nothing to go by except the OP's understanding. And he's the one asking the questions.

Comment: You are a bit off, the start+stop bit goes with each byte, not the entire string. So it would be 14 * (8+2) * 80 = 11200 bits/sec. It works better if you assume the dash is a figment of the OP's imagination: 12 * (8+2) * 80 = 9600 bits/sec.  Nice round number, not very likely since such a device will surely send extra characters to mark the start and/or end of the data packet.